# Difference histogram Excel/Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, histogram

I'm trying to figure out the difference between histograms made on Matlab (using the function 'hist' and 'histc" and one made on excel2007.

The following is my data:

```
92.75408677
94.30203471
39.29203084
39.69600648
169.599791
47.69892422
55.70547521
45.68462703
47.87167045
40.44786332
166.2861124
113.4816594
100.4448781
47.82555238
```

I use the following bins

```
0
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
110
120
130
140
150
160
170
180
```

Here are the results of the different frequencies using the different softwares and different functions:

```
bins    Histc-Matlab    Excel   Hist-Matlab
    0   0   0   0
    10  0   0   0
    20  0   0   0
    30  2   0   0
    40  5   2   3
    50  1   5   4
    60  0   1   1
    70  0   0   0
    80  0   0   0
    90  2   0   2
    100 1   2   1
    110 1   1   1
    120 0   1   0
    130 0   0   0
    140 0   0   0
    150 0   0   0
    160 2   0   0
    170 0   2   2
    180 0   0   0
```

I'm confused why are they all different? Can anyone explain me that?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just info from manuals:

n = hist(Y,x) where x is a vector, returns the distribution of Y among length(x) bins **with centers specified by x**.

n = histc(x,edges) counts the number of values in vector x that fall **between the elements in the edges vector** (which must contain monotonically non-decreasing values). n is a length(edges) vector containing these counts. **n(k) counts the value x(i) if edges(k) <= x(i) < edges(k+1)**. The last bin counts any values of x that match edges(end).

Excel counts the number of data points in each data bin. A data point is included in a particular data bin if the number **is greater than the lowest bound and equal to or less than the greater bound for the data bin**.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that hist makes the bins centered on the center of the edges you make, like: 35-45, there are the following numbers: 39.29, 39.69 and 40.44, so it marks (3), while the histc uses the exact edges you tell the function to use, so 30-40 it marks (2), and, finally, excel uses same as histc, but translated 1 position ahead.